# Can't save pasted email code

Tags: email, html5

I've been trying to paste some email code into the edit section, and I cannot save. I am not getting any error code really, just a message that says "An unexpected error has occurred". I called sales force, and they said it was probably an invalid character from pasted code. However, I hand coded the email myself, and I have never had this issue before. Has anyone had this problem? Does anyone have suggestions as to what may have caused this?

I've narrowed it down to this bit of code.

```
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="columns-container" width="100%" bgcolor="#e5edca">
              <tr>
                <td class="force-col" valign="top">

                  <!-- ### COLUMN 2 ### -->
                  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" width="500" class="col-2" id="last-col-2">
                    <tr>
                      <td class="center-text" align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:13px; line-height: 20px; color: #666666;letter-spacing: 1px;font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;">
                        <br class="hideme">
                        <div style="font-size: 15px;line-height: 15px;">Just a few more points to earn your <strong>$5</strong> voucher! Get <strong>$5</strong> for your first <strong>500</strong> points earned and <strong>$1</strong> for every <strong>100</strong> points after.</div>
                        <br>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>

                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
```

Comment: Without seeing the email its hard to say, but I've had issues where quotes (") have jacked up things when copying and pasting stuff.

Comment: Like quotes in a <p> tag or <span> or something?

Comment: Copy the email into notepad, and then try.. It may get rid of any of the weird formatting

Comment: I'm on a mac, so no notepad unfortunately. I'm using atom right now.

Comment: @KathrynCrawford - Same thing if you copy and paste into textedit then copy and paste into salesforce

Comment: Try switching browsers?

Comment: How about removing all %%[ IF @phase == '4N' OR phase == '10N' THEN ]%% these tags .Not sure why you have %% tags

Comment: Try to remove tags one by one to figure which tag causes issues

Comment: The tags are ASP code. I ended up narrowing it down to a div tag where I had copied and pasted some text from photoshop.

Answer (score 3):

After narrowing it down to that one table, I ended up rewriting the div with text in it by hand. I guess I may have copied that text block and something weird got copied over. Guess I learned my lesson about copying and pasting from photoshop!

Comment: a non UTF-8 char could have done it

Comment: Yeah, that's true. Whatever it was, it wasn't visible to my eye. So weird.